# Summing the columns for every variable in data frame by groups using R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data.frame like follows

```
    table=data.frame(ID=c(rep("Be_01",8),rep("Ce_02",5)),Orig=c("Car","Bus","Truck","Car","Bus","Car","Bike","Truck","Car","Truck","Bus","Bike","Bike"),Orig_counts=c(5,9,8,10,14,4,8,6,10,3,9,10,6), Replace=c("Bike","Truck","Bus","Truck","Truck","Bike","Car","Bus","Bike","Bike","Truck","Car","Car"),Replace_Count=c(9,4,2,7,10,11,12,6,7,5,9,4,2))
>table
         ID  Orig Orig_counts Replace Replace_Count
      Be_01   Car           5    Bike             9
      Be_01   Bus           9   Truck             4
      Be_01 Truck           8     Bus             2
      Be_01   Car          10   Truck             7
      Be_01   Bus          14   Truck            10
      Be_01   Car           4    Bike            11
      Be_01  Bike           8     Car            12
      Be_01 Truck           6     Bus             6
      Ce_02   Car          10    Bike             7
      Ce_02 Truck           3    Bike             5
      Ce_02   Bus           9   Truck             9
      Ce_02  Bike          10     Car             4
      Ce_02  Bike           6     Car             2
```

I would like sum the Replace_counts for all rows having entry "Car" in column Orig and "Bike" in the columns Replace and vice versa. I would like output as follows

```
ID    Bike_and_Cars Cars_and_Bike
Be_01        12          20  
Ce_02        6           7
```

Is it possible to achieve this by aggregate function in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of not answering the exact question you asked, you might be better served by a more general approach to this.

```
> aggregate(Replace_Count ~ ID + Orig + Replace, data=table, sum)
     ID  Orig Replace Replace_Count
1 Be_01   Car    Bike            20
2 Ce_02   Car    Bike             7
3 Ce_02 Truck    Bike             5
4 Be_01 Truck     Bus             8
5 Be_01  Bike     Car            12
6 Ce_02  Bike     Car             6
7 Be_01   Bus   Truck            14
8 Ce_02   Bus   Truck             9
9 Be_01   Car   Truck             7
```

From here it would be fairly easy to extract that subset of data that most interests you.  One way to do that would be to create a combined column, say

```
table$Move <- with(table, paste0(Orig,"_and_",Replace))
```

And then spread the data out, say, with `tidyr` (you could use `reshape2` as well)

```
spread(aggregate(Replace_Count ~ ID + Move, data=table, sum), Move, Replace_Count)
     ID Bike_and_Car Bus_and_Truck Car_and_Bike Car_and_Truck Truck_and_Bike
1 Be_01           12            14           20             7             NA
2 Ce_02            6             9            7            NA              5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with split-apply-combine. Here is a solution in base R, using the `split` function to split up your data frame by ID, the `lapply` function to summarize each ID-specific subset of your data, and the `do.call` function with `rbind` to combine the summarized data from each ID.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x) {
  data.frame(ID=x$ID[1],
             Bike_and_Cars=sum(x$Replace_Count[x$Orig == "Bike" & x$Replace=="Car"]),
             Cars_and_Bike=sum(x$Replace_Count[x$Orig == "Car" & x$Replace == "Bike"]))
}))
#          ID Bike_and_Cars Cars_and_Bike
# Be_01 Be_01            12            20
# Ce_02 Ce_02             6             7
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Will the above code work on a data frame similar to above data frane where all columns all factors ?

Comment: @deena yes, as long as Replace_Count is numeric then it does not matter if ID, Orig, or Replace are factors or strings.